# AttributedString Not working with UILabel

Tags: swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have the below code, that runs in viewDidLoad.

```
    let text = "\n \t What is a Call?"

    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)])
    
    textLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

When it runs, nothing gets set in the label. However, if I set it like this

```
textLabel.text = text
```

I see the attributed text? Why doesn't the previous line of code work?

Answer (score 3):

I tried adding your code to a completely clean project and found two potential issues. Maybe you have thought of both of them but I couldn't read that from your question so here goes :)

### Number of Lines

It *is* a bit tricky but when you add a `\n` in your text, that also means that if you haven't explicitly told your `UILabel` to take that into consideration, it will only show the first line...which is empty in your case :)

So, try adding

`textLabel.numberOfLines = 0`

to tell your `UILabel` to use as many lines as is needed for the text.

### Size of Your Label

I don't know how you've set up your label, but it could be that the size reserved for the label is too small for all of it to be shown on the screen. You can use the [visual debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html) to examine the view hierarchy and see if that can give you any clues.

If I set `numberOfLines` to 0 and added constraints to the `textLabel` so it had sufficient space, I was able to see "What is a Call?" in glorious 30 point bold system font on my view so...you're close :)